# Use of pytorch dataset for model inference- GPU

Tags: pytorch, dataset, gpu, huggingface-transformers

I am running T5-base-grammar-correction for grammer correction on my dataframe with text column

```
from happytransformer import HappyTextToText
from happytransformer import TTSettings
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

happy_tt = HappyTextToText("T5",  "./t5-base-grammar-correction")
beam_settings =  TTSettings(num_beams=5, min_length=1, max_length=30)
def grammer_pipeline(text):
    text = "gec: " + text
    result = happy_tt.generate_text(text, args=beam_settings)
    
    return result.text

df['new_text'] =  df['original_text'].progress_apply(grammer_pipeline)
```

Pandas apply function, though runs and provides required results, but runs quite **slow**.

Also I get the below warning while executing the code

```
/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py:908: UserWarning: You seem to be using the pipelines sequentially on GPU. In order to maximize efficiency please use a dataset
  UserWarning,
```

I have access to GPU. Can somebody provide some pointers to speed up the execution and utilising full capabilities of GPU

--------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

I tried using pytorch Dataset in the below way, but still the processing is slow:

```
class CustomD(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.len = text.shape[0]
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.text[idx]
        text = "gec: " + text
        result = happy_tt.generate_text(text, args=beam_settings)
        return result.text 

TD = GramData(df.original_text)
final_data = DataLoader(dataset=TD,
                          batch_size=10,
                          shuffle=False
                         )
import itertools
list_modified=[]
for (idx, batch) in enumerate(final_data):
    list_modified.append(batch)



flat_list = [item for sublist in list_modified for item in sublist]
df["new_text"]=flat_list
```

Comment: Define "slow". Also, what kind of GPU do you have access to, and is it currently successfully utilizing it (for single samples per row)?

Comment: It takes ~100s for processing 200 samples. And while running with pandas apply it gives warning "You seem to be using the pipelines sequentially on GPU. In order to maximize efficiency please use a dataset"

Even with pytorch Dataset, it is still the same with same warning. I think the above code is not able to utilize GPU parallel processing. I need help with the same